# Converting GMT to EST from CSV file using Python

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I have a CSV file that has a date column and a time column.  The time column is in GMT (24hr format) and I need to convert it to EST.  Because it is daylight saving time, the time differential now is -5 hours here on the east coast.  I need a way to read the CSV file and subtract 5 hours from all of the times in the column.  My biggest problem is that many of the conversions would cover two days.  For example, "Thu Nov 7,0:30" would convert to "Thu Nov 6,19:30".  If the date and time converts to the previous day, I need to change the date in the CSV.  Here is a sample of the data I am using:

Date,Time

Wed Nov 6,0:01

Wed Nov 6,0:30

Wed Nov 6,8:00

Wed Nov 6,13:30

Thu Nov 7,0:30

Thu Nov 7,2:00

Thu Nov 7,5:00

Thu Nov 7,15:30

Thu Nov 7,20:00

Fri Nov 8,0:30

Fri Nov 8,2:30

Fri Nov 8,6:45

Fri Nov 8,9:30

Fri Nov 8,13:30

Fri Nov 8,17:00

Sat Nov 9,1:30

Sat Nov 9,5:30

Sun Nov 10,21:45

Sun Nov 10,23:50

Here is how I'd like the data to look after the -5 hour conversion:

Date,Time

Wed Nov 5,19:01

Wed Nov 6,19:30

Wed Nov 6,3:00

Wed Nov 6,8:30

Thu Nov 6,19:30

Thu Nov 6,21:00

Thu Nov 7,0:00

Thu Nov 7,10:30

Thu Nov 7,15:00

Fri Nov 7,19:30

Fri Nov 7,21:30

Fri Nov 8,1:45

Fri Nov 8,4:30

Fri Nov 8,8:30

Fri Nov 8,12:00

Sat Nov 8,20:30

Sat Nov 9,0:30

Sun Nov 10,16:45

Sun Nov 10,18:50

I have some code to determine the status of DST (-4 hours or -5 hours).  I need help reading the CSV file, iterating through the time column, subtracting the correct number of hours, and changing any corresponding dates if the time/date changes to the previous day.  I'm using Python 2.7.5

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: The classic question pops again! What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean UTC when you say GMT? Note: EST abbreviation is by itself ambiguous e.g., it may refer to Australia/Melbourne (though `-5` hours point to America).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use datetime and pytz. These are the steps you should follow:

First, obviously, parse the csv and load every line into a naive datetime object (without timezone).

Second, make the datetime objects timezone aware:

```
src_tz = pytz.timezone('GMT')
dt = src_tz.localize(dt)
```

Then convert them to the timezone you want:

```
dst_tz = pytz.timezone('EST')
dt = dt.astimezone(dst_tz)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?  This looks like something I want to expand on.  Can you include an example for reading the CSV into a naive date time object and writing the changes to a new file?  Sorry but I'm not a programmer, I'm a biology doctorate student.

Comment: @Pismo, it's not reasonable to expect us to write your whole program for you.  If you search StackOverflow you will find multiple questions about reading/writing CSV, and if you Google for "Python CSV tutorial" you will find lots of help.  If you get stuck, post a question about your problem with CSV, but really that ground has been well-covered and you can probably answer your questions just by searching previous questions.  Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I think the `pytz` answer is cleaner than this one, but I'll leave this here to show the general case.  If you ever found that a clock was 23 minutes fast or something, this technique would let you correct timestamps.  But `pytz` looks like it is the easiest way to handle timezone conversions.

Use `datetime` to convert the date string into a single number (timestamp value, the number of seconds since the "epoch").  Subtract the desired time by converting to seconds (5 hours == 5 * 60 * 60).  Then use `datetime` to convert the number back to a timestamp string.

`datetime` will handle the edge cases for you, such as the calender date changing.  It should even do the right thing when you are subtracting a timestamp that would be affected by a change in daylight savings time or a leap second or something.

EDIT: here's code that uses `calendar` and `time` but doesn't actually use `datetime`.  I'm out of time to look at this... In my testing it printed "Nov 6" instead of "Nov 06" as you wanted, but this is close to what you want.

Strip whitespace from around the timestamp before passing it to this function.

```
import calendar
import time

def convert_ts(timestamp, change):
    temp = time.strptime(timestamp, "%a %b %d,%H:%M")
    t = calendar.timegm(temp)
    t += change
    temp = time.gmtime(t)
    return time.strftime("%a %b %0d,%H:%M", temp)
```

EDIT: Okay, here is a complete program that implements the above and includes test cases.  When I tested the above I found that the weekdays weren't right, and I figured that was because the timestamps don't include year.  So, I added a `default_year` argument.

You could write code to figure out the current year, and I'll add that if anyone asks for it.

```
s = """\
Wed Nov 6,0:01 
Wed Nov 6,0:30 
Wed Nov 6,8:00 
Wed Nov 6,13:30 
Thu Nov 7,0:30 
Thu Nov 7,2:00 
Thu Nov 7,5:00 
Thu Nov 7,15:30 
Thu Nov 7,20:00 
Fri Nov 8,0:30 
Fri Nov 8,2:30 
Fri Nov 8,6:45 
Fri Nov 8,9:30 
Fri Nov 8,13:30 
Fri Nov 8,17:00 
Sat Nov 9,1:30 
Sat Nov 9,5:30 
Sun Nov 10,21:45 
Sun Nov 10,23:50"""
data = [line.strip() for line in s.split('\n')]

s = """\
Tue Nov 5,19:01 
Tue Nov 5,19:30 
Wed Nov 6,3:00 
Wed Nov 6,8:30 
Wed Nov 6,19:30 
Wed Nov 6,21:00 
Thu Nov 7,0:00 
Thu Nov 7,10:30 
Thu Nov 7,15:00 
Thu Nov 7,19:30 
Thu Nov 7,21:30 
Fri Nov 8,1:45 
Fri Nov 8,4:30 
Fri Nov 8,8:30 
Fri Nov 8,12:00 
Fri Nov 8,20:30 
Sat Nov 9,0:30 
Sun Nov 10,16:45 
Sun Nov 10,18:50"""
correct = [line.strip() for line in s.split('\n')]

import calendar
import time
import re

pat_lead0 = re.compile(r'([ ,])0(\d)')

def convert_ts(timestamp, default_year, change):
    temp = time.strptime(timestamp + " %04d" % default_year, "%a %b %d,%H:%M %Y")
    t = calendar.timegm(temp)
    t += change
    temp = time.gmtime(t)
    s = time.strftime("%a %b %0d,%H:%M", temp)
    s = re.sub(pat_lead0, r'\1\2', s)
    return s

offset = -5 * 60 * 60  # seconds in five hours
for s, k in zip(data, correct):
    result = convert_ts(s, 2013, offset)
    if result != k:
        print("result: '{}'  correct: '{}'".format(result, k))
print("Done.")
```